# why won't my program print a list from a large data file?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have to print a list of months from a large data file (months are classified as 1=january, 2=february, 3=march, etc) but the program is only printing lists of 1s even though there are there months in the data file

I've printed out the months by themselves, not as a list, ad they print just fine. It only happens when I try to print them out as a list

```
import numpy as np
import csv
with open('FileName') as i:
    j = csv.reader(i, delimiter='\t')
    for row in j:
        next(j)
        print(row[2])
```

I expected an output with all of the number months in one list, but the list is only 1s

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use pandas assuming that the csv file u have has column names in it
Try adding sample csv so that it would be easy to give solution.

```
import pandas
colnames = ["name1","name2","month"]
data = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv",names=colnames)
```

to get the list of months just use this

```
month = data.month.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need

```
next(j)
```

This works:

```
j = iter([1,2,3])
for month in j:
  print(month)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

But it does not work if I put next(j).

Answer (score 0):

you didnt get expected output, because your are printing row[2] in for loop. eventually you will get evry item in list in a loop.

try to append into another list, you will endup with everything in one list, as you wanted.